# How to iterate through a list of list in jsp

Tags: jsp-tags, listiterator

I have list of list in a java class. I want to display list of list in JSP.

Java code

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> criteriaList;//have getter,setter
```

JSP Code

```
<s:iterator value="criteriaList"  status="status">
  <tr><td>
     <s:property value="[#status.index]" />
  </tr></td>
 </s:iterator>
```

But can't working.

Answer (score 0):

As copied out of the struts documentation.

**Iterating over a list of lists**

```
    <table>
        <s:iterator value="grid">
        <tr>
            <s:iterator value="top">
                <td><s:property/></td>
            </s:iterator>
        </tr>
        </s:iterator>
     </table>
```

The trick here is to use 'top' as the value for the inner iterator. This example probably uses a two-dimensional array, but you can use the pattern for any list of lists.

Comment: List of list I think accessible by index, can't reference by object such as above example.

Comment: As is said. I literally copied this from the struts examples page, haven't tested it but assuming they did before publishing it.